# Generating lists of data with ReplacePart

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following example:

```
data = {{a, a1, a2}, {b, b1, b2}, {c, c1, c2}, {d, d1, d2}};
repa = {a11, a12, a13};
repb = {b11, b12, b13};
repc = {c11, c12, c13};
newData = 
 MapThread[
  ReplacePart[data, {{1, 2} -> #1, {2, 2} -> #2}] &, {repa, repb}]
```

Which generates:

```
{{{a, a11, a2}, {b, b11, b2}, {c, c1, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}, {{a, a12, 
   a2}, {b, b12, b2}, {c, c1, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}, {{a, a13, a2}, {b, 
   b13, b2}, {c, c1, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}}
```

Now, what if I want to continue in a similar way, and generate on this the following:

```
{...,{{a, a11, a2}, {b, b11, b2}, {c, c11, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}, {{a, a12, 
       a2}, {b, b12, b2}, {c, c12, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}, {{a, a13, a2}, {b, 
       b13, b2}, {c, c13, c2}, {d, d1, d2}}}
```

where the dots represent the expression above without the outer {} or even something uglier by making the copy of the above and then extending it by replacing `d1->{d11,d12,d13}` analogously?
What would be the best way? Also is there a way without stacking the operators which implies that i have to know how many variations I need to make?

Also I would be glad with any comments, on the current implementation of [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)+[`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html), is there a better way?

Comment: At least, you can do `MapThread[ReplacePart[data, {{1, 2} -> #1, {2, 2} -> #2, {3, 2} -> #3, {4, 2} -> #4}] &, {repa, repb, repc, repd}]`, because `MapThread` is generalizable to more than two inputs, but there's certainly a better way. I will think on it.

Answer (score 1):

The direct generalization of your code would be to take advantage of the fact that `MapThread` works for functions with more than two arguments. Therefore, if

```
data = {{a, a1, a2}, {b, b1, b2}, {c, c1, c2}, {d, d1, d2}};
repa = {a11, a12, a13};
repb = {b11, b12, b13};
repc = {c11, c12, c13};
repd = {d11, d12, d13};
```

then

```
newData = MapThread[
   ReplacePart[data, {{1, 2} -> #1, {2, 2} -> #2, {3, 2} -> #3, {4, 2} -> #4}] &,
   {repa, repb, repc, repd}
  ]
(* { {{a, a11, a2}, {b, b11, b2}, {c, c11, c2}, {d, d11, d2}},
     {{a, a12, a2}, {b, b12, b2}, {c, c12, c2}, {d, d12, d2}},
     {{a, a13, a2}, {b, b13, b2}, {c, c13, c2}, {d, d13, d2}} } *)
```

We can automate this somewhat via the following:

```
newData = With[
   {f = Table[{j, 2} -> Slot[j], {j, 4}]},
   MapThread[ReplacePart[data, f] &, {repa, repb, repc, repd}]
  ]
```

The following method has the advantage of not requiring hard-coding the number of lists (i.e. 4 for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in this case), but it has the *dis*advantage of not working if there are repeated elements in the each sublist of `data`:

```
newData = Transpose@MapThread[
   #1 /. List /@ Thread[#1[[2]] -> #2] &,
   {data, {repa, repb, repc, repd}}
  ]
```